error TS2307 for the workspace package dependency
The @d-matrix/icons-react package is an dependency for @d-matrix/icons-site package. Try to use GitHub Actions to deploy a static HTML built from @d-matrix/icons-site package as GitHub Pages.
npm workspace:
$ tree -L 2 -I node_modules
.
|-- LICENSE
|-- README.md
|-- package-lock.json
|-- package.json
`-- packages
    |-- icons-react
    `-- icons-site

3 directories, 4 files

packages/icons-site/package.json:
{
  "name": "@d-matrix/icons-site",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc -b && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@d-matrix/icons-react": "^0.0.6",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.15.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.4",
    "eslint": "^9.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.14",
    "globals": "^15.12.0",
    "typescript": "~5.6.2",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "vite": "^6.0.1"
  }
}

.github/workflows/static.yml:
name: Deploy static content to Pages

on:
  push:
    branches: ['main']

  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: read
  pages: write
  id-token: write

concurrency:
  group: 'pages'
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 18
          cache: 'npm'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build:site --verbose
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v4
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v3
        with:
          # Upload dist folder
          path: './packages/icons-site/dist'
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v4

package.json:
{
  "name": "dm-icons",
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/icons-react",
    "packages/icons-site"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "generate": "npm run generate --workspace=@d-matrix/icons-react",
    "predev": "npm run generate && npm run ref",
    "dev": "npm run dev --workspace=@d-matrix/icons-site",
    "ref": "npm i @d-matrix/icons-react -w @d-matrix/icons-site",
    "build:site": "npm run build --workspace=@d-matrix/icons-site"
  }
}

Run npm run build:site --verbose
  npm run build:site --verbose
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
npm verbose cli /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.5/x64/bin/node /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.5/x64/bin/npm
npm info using npm@10.8.2
npm info using node@v18.20.5
npm verbose title npm run build:site
npm verbose argv "run" "build:site" "--loglevel" "verbose"
npm verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/home/runner/.npm/_logs/2024-12-20T08_32_38_796Z-
npm verbose logfile /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2024-12-20T08_32_38_796Z-debug-0.log
> build:site
> npm run build --workspace=@d-matrix/icons-site
npm verbose cli /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.5/x64/bin/node /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.5/x64/bin/npm
npm info using npm@10.8.2
npm info using node@v18.20.5
npm verbose title npm run build
npm verbose argv "run" "build" "--workspace" "@d-matrix/icons-site"
npm verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/home/runner/.npm/_logs/2024-12-20T08_32_38_920Z-
npm verbose logfile /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2024-12-20T08_32_38_920Z-debug-0.log
> @d-matrix/icons-site@0.0.0 build
> tsc -b && vite build
Error: src/App.tsx(1,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@d-matrix/icons-react' or its corresponding type declarations.
npm verbose stack Error: command failed
npm verbose stack     at promiseSpawn (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.5/x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:22:22)
npm verbose stack     at spawnWithShell (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.5/x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:124:10)
npm verbose stack     at promiseSpawn (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.5/x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:12:12)
npm verbose stack     at runScriptPkg (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.5/x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/lib/run-script-pkg.js:77:13)
npm verbose stack     at runScript (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.5/x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/lib/run-script.js:9:12)
npm verbose stack     at #run (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.5/x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/run-script.js:130:13)
npm verbose stack     at RunScript.execWorkspaces (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.5/x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/run-script.js:62:24)
npm verbose stack     at async Npm.exec (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.5/x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:207:9)
npm verbose stack     at async module.exports (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.5/x64/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli/entry.js:74:5)
npm verbose pkgid @d-matrix/icons-site@0.0.0
npm error Lifecycle script `build` failed with error:
npm error code 2
npm error path /home/runner/work/dm-icons/dm-icons/packages/icons-site
npm error workspace @d-matrix/icons-site@0.0.0
npm error location /home/runner/work/dm-icons/dm-icons/packages/icons-site
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c tsc -b && vite build
npm verbose cwd /home/runner/work/dm-icons/dm-icons
npm verbose os Linux 6.5.0-1025-azure
npm verbose node v18.20.5
npm verbose npm  v10.8.2
npm verbose exit 2
npm verbose code 2
npm verbose cwd /home/runner/work/dm-icons/dm-icons
npm verbose os Linux 6.5.0-1025-azure
npm verbose node v18.20.5
npm verbose npm  v10.8.2
npm verbose exit 2
npm verbose code 2
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.

I don't know why the build fails when using GitHub Actions. The build npm script run successfully in local machine.
$ npm run build:site

> build:site
> npm run build --workspace=@d-matrix/icons-site


> @d-matrix/icons-site@0.0.0 build
> tsc -b && vite build

vite v6.0.3 building for production...
✓ 45 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                   0.48 kB │ gzip:  0.31 kB
dist/assets/index-dYOE1zTs.css    0.19 kB │ gzip:  0.16 kB
dist/assets/index-D70fpBM4.js   160.81 kB │ gzip: 51.67 kB
✓ built in 873ms

Tried the solutions: tsc throws `TS2307: Cannot find module` for a local file, none of them work.
GitHub Repo

I changed the workflow steps like below:
jobs:
  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: 18
          cache: 'npm'

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Build icons
        run: npm run build:icons --verbose
      - name: Reference icons
        run: npm run ref
      - name: Build site
        run: npm run build:site --verbose
      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v4
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v3
        with:
          # Upload dist folder
          path: './packages/icons-site/dist'
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v4

Then it works


It seems that @d-matrix/icons-react package is working well on your local environment. but the package doesn't works on GitHub Actions environment. this means you didn't set up the package correctly on github actions environment.
so you need to check  workspace dependencies are Installed correctly using this command.
name: Install dependencies run: npm install --workspaces
It's just my opinion.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
